# Any active solar X-ray imager in orbit?

Tags: the-sun, space-telescope, artificial-satellite, solar-flare, x-ray

NOAA GOES-14 & 15 went very recently [in storage mode](https://www.swpc.noaa.gov/news/goes-14-15-are-now-storage-mode). With those also went the [solar X-ray imagers (SXI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_X-ray_Imager), as GOES-16 & 17 do not have such instruments on board. Hence, my question:

Are there still any active solar X-ray imagers of other space agencies orbiting the Earth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Hinode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinode_(satellite)) satellite has an active x-ray telescope that is routinely used to image the sun.  And the [NuSTAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuSTAR) extreme x-ray telescope can also be used for sun imaging (although its main job is looking for black holes)

Here is the [latest XRT image](https://hinode.nao.ac.jp/en/gallery/latest/) of Hinode

There are also Extreme Ultraviolet telescopes (at 171Å that is less than an octave away from the conventional lower end of X-rays at 100Å) SDO. Stereo (Ahead) and SOHO all have EUV telescopes. The Atmospheric Imaging Assembly on the [SDO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Dynamics_Observatory) satellite has sensors for wavelengths as short as 94Å, conventionally classed as X-rays

https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/nustar/searing-sun-seen-in-x-rays

Comment: Here is the [**latest XRT image of Hinode**](https://hinode.nao.ac.jp/en/gallery/latest/) that I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll incorporate your suggestion.